# Including quote characters in a literal string

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I need to execute this line in Visual C++:

```
system("msbuild "C:\\Users\\...\\...\\...\\...\\...\\....\\EDA - Motif.vcxproj"");
```

But I'm having trouble with these symbols `""` ...

Is there an alternative for using other symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \" to put a " inside a string, just like you used \\ to put a \ inside a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the escape character for this:

```
system("msbuild \"C:\\Users\\...\\...\\...\\...\\...\\....\\EDA - Motif.vcxproj\"");
```